# Not working binding.pry when executing by eval inside pry-session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

For speed up development process, I'm using file `zze.rb`, which I edit in my IDE and reload in pry console with short command `zze` (zz - uncommon beginning for variable/method names; e - execute). This way I can stop execution process in any point of my application by `binding.pry` and can execute code many times, not waiting of full Rails environment restart each time.

I have this code in my `.pryrc` file:

```
Pry.config.commands.command "zze", 'Execute all from .pry_exec/zze.rb' do
  Dir['.pry_exec/autoload/**/*.rb']
      .delete_if {|file| File.basename(file) =~ /^_/}  # inore files that starting form underscore '_'
      .each { |f| load(f) }

  file_name = File.absolute_path '.pry_exec/zze.rb'
  code = File.open(file_name, 'r') {|f| f.read}
  eval(code, @target, file_name)
end
```

and have folder `<myproject>/.pry_exec/`:

```
<myproject>/.pry_exec/    # ignored from CVS
  autoload/               # this folder loads automatically each `zze` call in cosnole
    some_class1.rb
    some_code2.rb
  zze.rb                  # this file loads automatically each `zze` call in console.
```

Sometimes there are cases, when it would be good to use `binding.pry`  inside `<myproject>/zze.rb` or `<myproject>/autoload/some_class1.rb` **but it does not working. It just ignore that.**

I also tried to rewrite `zze`-code this way:

```
# ~/.pryrc
def zze(name = nil)
  Dir['.pry_exec/autoload/**/*.rb']
      .delete_if {|file| File.basename(file) =~ /^_/}  # inore files that starting form underscore '_'
      .each { |f| load(f) }

  load ".pry_exec/#{name || 'zze'}.rb"
  # instance_eval(File.read(".pry_exec/#{name || 'zze'}.rb"))
end
```

but it also ignore `binding.pry` inside `<myproject>/zze.rb` or `<myproject>/autoload/some_class1.rb`

Also when `zze` is not pry-command, but is method, code from `zze.rb` executes inside another scope, and I will not have access to local variables defined from `zze.rb` in my pry-main context. Didn't find how to fix that yet with short way.